# Convert a dictionary in string for to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am using requests within python and getting a string output in the form:
`{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`.

I am then using flask to return the output and trying to turn it into a table within my html template.

```
some_output = response.text
return render_template('the-template.html', some_output=some_output)
```

printing some_output gives : `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`

within the template i am trying:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         {% for key, value in some_output.items() %}
            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

When i submit the page to get the output i get the following error message:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items'

How can i convert this string object into a dictionary so i can turn the dictionary into an **html** table within the template??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json.loads` to convert the string to a dictionary object:

```
import json
some_output = response.text
return render_template('the-template.html', some_output=json.loads(some_output))
```

Comment: Can just use `response.json()` and avoid importing the json module